# Google Chart Kind of functionality

Tags: php, image, dynamic

I am developing a feature and came around a situation where I want the following kind of functionality:

http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World

I am wondering how its possible?
What I need is an Image Name Passed as Parameter and a text passed as parameter, it would return me Hello World written on the iMage.

For example,
http://myurl.com?image=imagename&text=HelloWorld
would return me "HelloWorld" written on the image(imagename passed as parameter)

How that's possible?